# Can my employer see the actual video chat if I use Facebook messenger on work WiFi?

Tags: privacy, wifi, facebook

I used my personal iPad over work WiFi (Verizon jetpack) to have a video chat with a friend over Facebook messenger. Can my employer actually see the video or just that I used messenger?

Comment: is your employer the NSA? probably just meta if not...

Comment: Lol no not nsa :)

Answer (score 4):

I will disagree with the other answers here:

Going directly to your specific scenario: You are using the company Wifi, so they control it and could capture its traffic. However two other important things are mentioned: you are using your *personal* device and acessing a service *outside of the company* that uses *SSL/TLS*. So they capture encrypted traffic.

Since it is your personal device and a service outside the company control, it is NOT trivial to sniff this TLS/SSL traffic. SSL sniffing *requires* control of your device trust anchors (trusted CAs) or control over the service endpoint, and that should NOT be the case on your *personal* iPad. One can only sniff an SSL connection using an MITM attack, and to have a MITM attack without a lot of warnings poping up (I guess the Messenger app would not even show a warning, would just not work) one needs to be able to inject trusted CAs on your device. That is common on company managed devices, but would not happen in a personal device (not without your explicit approval, at least).

Comment: SSL decryption is easily done by many companies by purchasing any number of various products.It's more a matter of, does your company have one of these products? If so, then yes, otherwise it's extraordinarily unlikely they're MITM you.
https://www.bluecoat.com/products-and-solutions/encrypted-traffic-management

Comment: @GingerBeard this type of sollution uses a MITM attack that, as I mentioned on the answer, requires control over the trusted CAs. It does NOT apply to private devices, only to the devices where the company can mess with the trust store.

Comment: You would merely have to accept the certificate when prompted decryption the traffic IS trivial assuming you accepted the certificate (which most end users will). 
I would agree that if you don't accept the certificate OR the company doesn't deploy one of these solutions then your standard MITM attack would be quite difficult to pull on one machine, much more a whole company.

Comment: Except that iPads messenger would probably not even ask if you want to accept the certificate. Not only is not easy, It is really not *possible* to the company to monitor his messenger traffic without his explicit permission (by installing the CA certificate). SSL exists exactly for protecting against that kind of monitoring/interception, so one can not say that SSL is easy to defeat just by having a privileged control of the network. It it was, it would be useless.

Comment: You also just can't convert data in the packets to video. It just doesn't work that way. As mentioned in my answer you would need some knowledge of FB's inner workings on their video chat client. Simply routing their traffic to your computer running that chat client isn't enough either.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the level of packet capture they are doing.

If they are doing full packet capture with ssl/tls interception then yes. You don't have to be the NSA to do this kind of interception but it is not something that most businesses will want to pay for.

Comment: TLS interception is far from trivial, without effective ownership of either the target device or the server. https://wiki.openrightsgroup.org/wiki/TLS_interception

Answer (score 1):

If it is your personal WiFi (Verizon jetpack) and you are running [WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access#WPA2) from your tablet to your Jetpack ... while it is possible for them to run a WiFi sniffer and/or a [MitM](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) proxy ... it is very unlikely.

Like `coffeethulhu` said [SSL/TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) can be can be intercepted and decrypted IF your company controls the network access you are using for your chat *(its actually pretty trivial if they are running a proxy server ... I have written my own [MitM](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) server in Node.js for testing purposes ... it was maybe 100 lines of code).*  However, if you are providing your own WiFi then it would be very hard and [very illegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_piggybacking) for them to intercept your traffic.

If it is your companies WiFi (Verizon jetpack) then chances are your company knows the WiFi key, and thus has access to the network (can legally sniff it) ... however, unless you are being routed back to your companies servers via VPN you are most likely going directly to a Verizon ISP ... in which case unless someone from your company was at your location with some type of WiFi sniffing tool ... its still very unlikely.

Traffic from your tablet is being encrypted at application level via [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) and then encrypted again via [WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access#WPA2) at the network level.  Your Jetpack then decrypts the [WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access#WPA2) and sends it via [LTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_%28telecommunication%29) (which i believe has its own encryption) to a Cell tower and from there it is outside of your company's control unless you are using your companies [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).  This means that if they wanted to intercept the traffic via sniffer from the jump between your tablet and the jetpack they would have to go through [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) and [WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access#WPA2) ... if they wanted to intercept the traffic via sniffer from the jump between your Jetpack and the Cell tower (also possible but less common) they would have to go through [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) and [LTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_%28telecommunication%29) ...

Is it possible, yes.  Is it trivial enough that a small company could accomplish it, no.

If you are super paranoid you could also add another layer of security by routing all of your web traffic through a personal [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) and/or [SSH tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

Comment: Not to nitpick, but for technological clarity, WPA2 happens at the physical layer, not network layer.

Comment: He said it's work Wifi, not personal.

Comment: @Lasagna yah, it was edited in after my answer so I edited my answer for both possibilities

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers there is a possibility to intercept the network traffic. It has been well covered in other answers so I won't bother diving into it again. However it is not as simple as capturing the packets and data. You can't encode network packets into video. So at this point you are looking at modifying their video messaging client to take the captured data to do this for you or creating your own video player to interact and use the data.

`CaffeineAddiction` mentioned how improbable it is to go through the trouble of sniffing the traffic. The improbability is increased when you add in the fact they need to be able to figure out how this data can be used to recreate the video.

So as long as your employer isn't skilled in network forensics, reverse engineering, and video encoding I would say you have nothing to worry about. Even for employers with such skills it would be a lot of work for a low reward. That is unless your employer was the NSA.

Answer (score 0):

> "I used my personal iPad over work WiFi (Verizon jetpack) to have a
>   video chat with a friend over Facebook messenger. Can my employer
>   actually see the video or just that I used messenger?"

Were you connected via VPN to the corporate network at the time?

If no, it's likely your employer can see neither. ISPs and telcos are not forthcoming about network traffic specifics without a court order ('we think he's wasting time on the clock' doesn't merit a subpoena), and Verizon is certainly not doing FPC on your encrypted video data. Without a VPN your traffic goes from your personal device through Verizon to the endpoint-- your employer wouldn't be in a position to intercept anything. Maybe corporate accounts are different (doubtful), but for personal accounts websites visited don't show up on billing statements.

If you were connected to a corporate VPN, they (should definitely be able to) see that you accessed Facebook, though assuming they were also MITMing your encrypted connection, storing and indexing streaming video data is a fool's errand unless you're the subject of an active investigation. It's a massive amount of data to collect on everyone in the enterprise and any hiccups in capturing would render the entire stream useless. So while entirely possible, anybody who set out to do it would just find themselves caching the entirety of YouTube several times over.

Assume you're safe, but don't do things like this on company equipment. You're asking for trouble.